# Exception when embedded Cassandra running multiple test cases: Keyspace ** does not exist

Tags: exception, junit, cassandra

The schema creation is done inside the target class SimpleRepo.java.

```
public class SimpleRepo {

    private Cluster cluster;

    private Session session;

    private String keyspace = "app";

    private String table = "myTable";

    @Autowired
    public SimpleRepo(Cluster cluster) {
        this.cluster = cluster;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        session = cluster.connect();
        createSchema();
    }

    public void createSchema() {
        .....
    }
}
```

When running the SimpleTest.java with one test case inside, it will pass. When running with two cases inside, only the first one passes and the second one throws out the exception: "com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Keyspace app does not exist".

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class, SimpleRepo.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@EmbeddedCassandra
public class SimpleTest {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleRepo simpleRepo;

    @Test
    public void testSave() throws Exception {
        ......
    }

    @Test
    public void testDel() throws IOException { 
        ......
    }
}

@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Cluster cluster() throws ConfigurationException, TTransportException, IOException, InterruptedException{
        EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra();

        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints("127.0.0.1")
                .withPort(9142)
                .build();

        return cluster;
    }
}
```

Why the keyspace created inside createSchema() would disappear when running the second test case? How to fix this problem? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: It would help if you show the test case code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener* calls *cleanServer()* after each test. That calls *EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.cleanEmbeddedCassandra()* which drops all non-system keyspaces.

Your code creates your keyspace only once, in *@PostConstruct*, so only 1st test case can use it.

It looks like you should use *@CassandraDataSet* to initialize a keyspace for each new test

https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/wiki/Spring-for-Cassandra-unit

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I tried to use @CassandraDataSet to initialize the keyspace if the keyspace doesn't exist. Now both cases can pass.